# Views/ Django How to read file and show on the page information from file csv

Tags: python, django, csv, view

Please help me to write code to show some values from the cvs file on site.
This is my views.py in Django project.
On the site views working and show all information from the file.But I need show info by searching for some value and show me line with this value.

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render




def index(request):
    with open('home/data.csv', 'r+', encoding='windows-1251') as file:
        csvfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
        data = pd.read_csv(csvfile.name)
        # You can create your custom dataframe here before converting it to html in next line
        data_html = data.to_html()
        context = {'loaded_data': data_html}
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context=data)
```

Mistake :

```
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'csv_file'
```

Comment: Well 'help me write code' is not legit stack question. If you want to process data sheets like CSV in python enviorments use pandas library. Here is the [link]https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Comment: @LuibaR . Do see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show some values from the `CSV` file on the site then consider using a library such as `pandas`. You can read more on that [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/)

Once you selected just the data you want to show on the site, you can then use the following method to convert pandas dataframe to HTML tables.

```
csvfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
data = pd.read_csv(csvfile.name)
#You can create your custom dataframe here before converting it to html in next line
data_html = data.to_html() 
context = {'loaded_data': data_html}
return render(request, "dataflow/table.html", context)
```

In the HTML page, use

```
{{loaded_data | safe}}
```

to render the table.

Comment: Hello, thanks for help.I am new in python, and do some mistakes.I tried to write as you say.But pycharn say mistake.And still does not work.

Comment: If possible, please update the error trace to the question

Comment: Your error just suggests that you don't have a dict key named `csv_file`

Comment: Where are you with this problem now?